# Ubuntu 20.04 taking too long to boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

I'm facing a very slow boot time while using Ubuntu,

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 9.143s (kernel) + 2min 4.895s (userspace) = 2min 14.038s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 4.885s in userspace
```

that's awfully long, I'm also not using a prehistoric machine, the processor is an Intel i5-4200M which is OK, should not take 2 minutes.

Also, I've faced this issue since I've first installed Ubuntu on this machine(about a year ago), I've reinstalled Ubuntu many times before, but the problem is still here.

```
$ systemd-analyze plot > init1.svg
```

gives me (Imgur doesnt support svg's so will have to do with link) : https://svgshare.com/i/Vx5.svg

Here is some extra info;

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
1min 20.804s vboxdrv.service                                      
 39.768s snapd.service                                        
 33.076s dev-sda6.device                                      
 21.262s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
 16.373s udisks2.service                                      
 12.864s NetworkManager.service                               
 12.204s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
 11.933s accounts-daemon.service                              
 11.776s apache2.service                                      
 11.567s dev-loop45.device                                    
 11.422s dev-loop48.device                                    
 11.399s dev-loop46.device                                    
 11.332s dev-loop44.device                                    
 11.246s dev-loop47.device                                    
 11.148s dev-loop30.device                                    
 11.116s ufw.service                                          
 10.892s dev-loop35.device                                    
 10.771s loadcpufreq.service                                  
 10.661s dev-loop43.device                                    
 10.430s dev-loop42.device                                    
 10.327s dev-loop39.device                                    
 10.234s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
 10.219s dev-loop41.device                                    
 10.110s dev-loop40.device                                    
  9.967s dev-loop37.device                                    
  9.944s dev-loop38.device                                    
  9.705s ModemManager.service                                 
  9.640s dev-loop36.device                                    
  9.466s dev-loop34.device                                    
  9.274s dev-loop33.device                                    
  9.041s thermald.service                                     
  8.999s dev-loop32.device                                    
  8.961s teamviewerd.service                                  
  8.926s dev-loop25.device                                    
  8.893s dev-loop27.device                                    
  8.864s dev-loop31.device                                    
  8.803s snap-anbox-186.mount                                 
  8.746s snap-authy-5.mount                                   
  8.731s dev-loop23.device                                    
  8.644s snap-cheat-2681.mount                                
  8.633s snap-cheat-2698.mount                                
  8.615s snap-cmake-834.mount                                 
  8.594s snap-cmake-846.mount                                 
  8.588s dev-loop29.device                                    
  8.545s wpa_supplicant.service                               
  8.487s snap-code-60.mount                                   
  8.467s dev-loop28.device                                    
  8.209s dev-loop26.device                                    
  8.045s dev-loop24.device                                    
  7.903s polkit.service                                       
  7.815s dev-loop22.device                                    
  7.794s dev-loop21.device                                    
  7.763s dev-loop19.device                                    
  7.494s dev-loop9.device                                     
  7.255s dev-loop8.device                                     
  7.112s avahi-daemon.service                                 
  7.084s dev-loop20.device                                    
  7.077s snap-code-61.mount                                   
  7.040s switcheroo-control.service                           
  7.033s systemd-logind.service                               
  6.921s dev-loop18.device                                    
  6.777s systemd-rfkill.service                               
  6.601s snap-core-10908.mount                                
  6.601s dev-loop17.device                                    
  6.594s snap-core-10958.mount                                
  6.560s dev-loop16.device                                    
  6.428s dev-loop15.device                                    
  6.300s snap-core18-1988.mount                               
  6.254s dev-loop14.device                                    
  6.099s dev-loop13.device                                    
  5.847s dev-loop11.device                                    
  5.833s dev-loop12.device                                    
  5.708s snap-core18-1997.mount                               
  5.666s snap-core20-904.mount                                
  5.582s dev-loop7.device                                     
  5.581s dev-loop10.device                                    
  5.447s gpu-manager.service                                  
  5.249s dev-loop0.device                                     
  5.245s dev-loop6.device                                     
  5.221s dev-loop2.device                                     
  5.058s dev-loop4.device                                     
  4.911s dev-loop1.device                                     
  4.811s dev-loop3.device                                     
  4.639s dev-loop5.device                                     
  4.619s grub-common.service                                  
  4.600s apt-daily-upgrade.service                            
  4.562s apport.service                                       
  4.118s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
  3.602s rsyslog.service                                      
  3.221s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
  2.904s snap-core20-975.mount                                
  2.877s snap-freecad-19.mount                                
  2.866s snap-freecad-22.mount                                
  2.831s snapd.apparmor.service                               
  2.609s lxc-net.service                                      
  2.208s apparmor.service                                     
  1.777s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount              
  1.776s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount               
  1.771s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount               
  1.702s snap-go-7013.mount                                   
  1.700s snap-go-7221.mount                                   
  1.693s snap-gradle-59.mount                                 
  1.680s snap-gradle-78.mount                                 
  1.678s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1513.mount              
  1.677s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount              
  1.675s snap-htop-2069.mount                                 
  1.660s snap-htop-2185.mount                                 
  1.622s snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-32.mount       
  1.617s lxc.service                                          
  1.608s snap-ncspot-85.mount                                 
  1.600s snap-nmap-2254.mount                                 
  1.567s snap-nmap-2280.mount                                 
  1.563s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
  1.535s snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-258.mount               
  1.524s snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-260.mount               
  1.510s snap-pdftk-9.mount                                   
  1.508s snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                         
  1.507s snap-snapd-11402.mount                               
  1.499s snap-snapd-11588.mount                               
  1.459s snap-spt-264.mount                                   
  1.458s snap-spt-271.mount                                   
  1.436s snap-telegram\x2dcli-34.mount                        
  1.429s systemd-resolved.service                             
  1.399s snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2480.mount                  
  1.384s snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2551.mount                  
  1.068s phpsessionclean.service                              
  1.054s systemd-udevd.service                                
  1.024s kerneloops.service                                   
   987ms pppd-dns.service                                     
   954ms upower.service                                       
   945ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
   941ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
   889ms systemd-modules-load.service                         
   794ms lm-sensors.service                                   
   785ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
   761ms swapfile.swap                                        
   702ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
   635ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
   605ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
   577ms plymouth-quit.service                                
   541ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
   457ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
   456ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
   455ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
   453ms keyboard-setup.service                               
   453ms systemd-journald.service                             
   452ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
   451ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
   442ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E3EC\x2dEBB0.service
   417ms snap-tetris\x2dthefenriswolf-4.mount                 
   400ms atopacct.service                                     
   399ms snap-tizonia-482.mount                               
   398ms snap-tizonia-503.mount                               
   350ms setvtrgb.service                                     
   344ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
   300ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
   275ms plymouth-start.service                               
   260ms sddm.service                                         
   226ms bluetooth.service                                    
   205ms systemd-random-seed.service                          
   201ms console-setup.service                                
   201ms snap-vlc-2103.mount                                  
   192ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d5\x2dstable-16.mount        
   166ms apport-autoreport.service                            
   160ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
   152ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-216.mount           
   149ms user@1000.service                                    
   145ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-212.mount           
   130ms boot-efi.mount                                       
   124ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
   101ms snapd.seeded.service                                 
    88ms openvpn.service                                      
    56ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
    46ms cpufrequtils.service                                 
    41ms motd-news.service                                    
    27ms vboxweb-service.service                              
    26ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
    25ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service                      
    24ms vboxautostart-service.service                        
     7ms alsa-restore.service                                 
     6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
     4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
     3ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
   596us snapd.socket
```

from here I can see that

1min 20.804s vboxdrv.service
39.768s snapd.service
33.076s dev-sda6.device
21.262s networkd-dispatcher.service
16.373s udisks2.service

are most probably the culprits, now is there a way to disable them? should I disable them completely? I have a /dev/sda6, so I don't think that should be disabled.

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 4.885s
└─multi-user.target @2min 4.885s
  └─vboxweb-service.service @2min 4.858s +27ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 9.043s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @56.838s +12.204s
        └─NetworkManager.service @43.973s +12.864s
          └─dbus.service @43.970s
            └─basic.target @43.948s
              └─sockets.target @43.948s
                └─snapd.socket @43.948s +596us
                  └─sysinit.target @43.868s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @41.036s +2.831s
                      └─apparmor.service @38.813s +2.208s
                        └─local-fs.target @38.812s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-anbox.mnt.mount @58.454s
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @57.779s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @7.442s
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @6.739s +702ms
                                  └─systemd-sysusers.service @6.102s +635ms
                                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @5.215s +124ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @4.761s
                                        └─system.slice @4.757s
                                          └─-.slice @4.757s
```

If you want anymore info, tell me, I'll add it.

Edit:

my dmesg output(too large so pastebin link) : https://pastebin.com/E1DdC5rT

Comment: Does this help :- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=273797 (see svideo)

Comment: @Keith5001 ok, I did that, edited my grub and updated it, however it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: My laptop originally came with a hard drive, and the same cpu. I upgraded to ssd and my boot time is not too long (+= 1min)

Comment: @Irsu85 ok my hard drive might be slowing down 'dev-sda6.device' but what about the other? ive disabled and masked snapd.service tho, can you tell me other services which I can similarly disable??

Comment: Btw if i "sudo systemctl disable some.service" and "sudo systemctl mask snapd.service" will I be able to use the service after startup? will other processes after start up be able to use it?

Comment: What Ubuntu version. I tried Xubuntu 20.10 with a 500Gb hard drive and had the same slow boot, took 10mins to boot. I think some oldish hard drive do not work well with later version. Try recovery mode, when I did this the boot was 20X faster

Comment: (I see you are trying 20.04) When I used a solid state drive the boot time is about ~5 seconds with the above Xubuntu 20.10

Comment: @Keith5001 Im using Ubuntu 20.04 with kde-desktop installed, with xanmod calcule 5.11 kernel. however boot is still very slow, using normal kernel and gnome.

Comment: if your hard drive slows down sda6, it will slow down all sda

Comment: @Irsu85 is it possible to mount a smaller sda first so faster boot, and then after boot, I Mount my larger 150 gb drive? could it be automated? so that it starts mounting rt after log in?

Comment: check the smart status of the drive using smartctl remapping sectors can cause a slow down

Comment: That should't work, because equal amount of data needs to be loaded (or more) and that will take the same (or more) time because the sda bandwidth needs to be shared over all sda partitions

Comment: just buy an ssd if you hear a hard drive spinning during boot time. This will cut your boot times AT LEAST in half